# If-else should not have break?

Tags: java, while-loop, break

So my professor mentioned that a break in an if/if-else statement is "bad" code.
What exactly does she mean by that? Also how am I able to fix my code that I currently have written, because it does work the way I want it to, it's just now I need to get ride of the break statement.

```
    int sumOne = 1;
    int sumTwo = 1;
    int sumOneTotal = 0;
    int sumTwoTotal = 0;
    while(sumOne > 0 || sumTwo > 0){
        System.out.print("Enter a number to add to first sum: ");
        //The user enters in a value for the first sum.
        sumOne = input.nextInt();

        /**
         * We use an if-else statment to ensure sumOne is never less than or equal to 0.
         * If it does it ends the program immediately and totals the sums.
         * This is because we only want the user to enter in positive numbers.
         */
        if (sumOne <= 0){
            break;
        }else{
            sumOneTotal = sumOneTotal + sumOne;
        }

        System.out.print("Enter a number to add to second sum: ");
        //The user enters in a value for the second sum.
        sumTwo = input.nextInt();

        /**
         * We use an if-else statment to ensure sumTwo is never less than or equal to 0. 
         * If it does it ends the program immediately and totals the sums.
         * This is because we only want the user to enter in positive numbers.
         */
        if (sumTwo <= 0){
            break;
        }else{
            sumTwoTotal = sumTwoTotal + sumTwo;
        }
    }
    //We print out the total of sumOneTotal and sumTwoTotal.
    System.out.printf("%1s%1d%12s%1s%1d", "First sum: ", sumOneTotal, " ", "Second sum: ", sumTwoTotal);
```

Essentially I want the user to enter ANY positive number and that number is added to the first or second sum. Once the user enters any number <= 0 I want the program to stop immediately. The issue that I keep having when I tinker with the code is that the code keeps running through. Meaning if I have the user enter in 0 to be added to the first sum, the code still asks the user to enter in a number for the second sum. I need it to stop right away and not continue. Any help would be a great help! I am using Java.

EDIT!!! So let's say hypothetically I want to make a program that does the exact same thing I am doing now just with no break statement. How would I do so? A few rules. The most outer statement must be a "while" loop. The inner workings of it can be anything. I also need the machine to print out "Enter a number to add to first sum:" and "Enter a number to add to second sum:" alternating. So if I entered in 1,2,3,4. The first sum would be 4 and the second sum would be 6. Last rule is that it can not contain any break statements!

Comment: The use of break is correct. Your teacher is wrong!

I will admit that it CAN be "bad code", but not when done correctly, like you have here..

Comment: You'll probably have to ask her what she means by that. Sounds like an over-generalization to me.

Comment: You should avoid using `break;` if you can, but sometimes avoiding `break;` is worse. In this case it would be worse IMHO.

Comment: The `else` isn't really necessary. You can just place the addition logic after the `if` since the `break` will stop processing in the loop.

Comment: Theory, meet Practice... Practice, meet Theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw the flowchart of your code you can see it exits a bucle in the middle of it, which isn't right, the right way is for it to exit when evaluated on the while, also when someone is reading your code they should expect the bucle is left when evaluated false on the while not in a random if inside the while block, I took your code and made some fixes to make it work as expected but I'm not sure if that's what your teacher expects.

```
    int sumOne = 1;
    int sumTwo = 1;
    int sumOneTotal = 0;
    int sumTwoTotal = 0;
    while (sumOne > 0 && sumTwo > 0) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number to add to first sum: ");
        // The user enters in a value for the first sum.
        sumOne = input.nextInt();

        /**
         * We use an if-else statment to ensure sumOne is never less than or
         * equal to 0. If it does it ends the program immediately and totals
         * the sums. This is because we only want the user to enter in
         * positive numbers.
         */
        if (sumOne > 0) {
            sumOneTotal = sumOneTotal + sumOne;
            System.out.print("Enter a number to add to second sum: ");
            // The user enters in a value for the second sum.
            sumTwo = input.nextInt();

            /**
             * We use an if-else statment to ensure sumTwo is never less
             * than or equal to 0. If it does it ends the program
             * immediately and totals the sums. This is because we only want
             * the user to enter in positive numbers.
             */
            if (sumTwo > 0) {
                sumTwoTotal = sumTwoTotal + sumTwo;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works!!! This problem was driving me insane because, while I did it right, she wasn't happy with the break statements!

Answer (score 6):

This is a throwback to when structured programming was a new thing, back when goto statements and the like were everywhere. In theory, *Ideally*, you should never have to use breaks/continues, and only have a single point of return. In reality, doing so *can* make your job a lot harder by making programs harder to write, harder to read, and take up more computing resources. Multiple returns, continues and breaks are middle men between truly structured programming and spaghetti code. Used properly, there is nothing wrong with them.

Generally, I've found that they will only obscure your code if you're already using bad practices that make your code hard to read (For example, writing huge blocks of logic without breaking it up, tightly coupling objects etc).

If you're interested, [here](http://homepages.tig.com.au/~ijoyner/Ian_Joyner/Structured_Programming.html) is a link to an interesting perspective on why NOT to use them. And [here](http://www.leepoint.net/JavaBasics/methods/method-commentary/methcom-30-multiple-return.html) is a perspective on why they are benefical.

Many others have already answered with code, but here is my shot :)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int sumOne = 1;
        int sumTwo = 1;
        int sumOneTotal = 0;
        int sumTwoTotal = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sumOne > 0 || sumTwo > 0){
            System.out.print("Enter a number to add to first sum: ");
            sumOne = input.nextInt();
            if (is_positive(sumOne)){
                sumOneTotal = sum_numbers(sumOneTotal, sumOne);
                System.out.print("Enter a number to add to second sum: ");
                sumTwo = input.nextInt();
                if(is_positive(sumTwo)){
                    sumTwoTotal = sum_numbers(sumTwoTotal, sumTwo);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%1s%1d%12s%1s%1d", "First sum: ", sumOneTotal, " ", "Second sum: ", sumTwoTotal);
        return;
    }
    public static int sum_numbers(int x, int y){
        int total = x + y;
        return total;
    }
    public static boolean is_positive(int x){
        boolean is_pos = true;
        if(x < 0){
            is_pos = false;
        }
        return is_pos;
    }
}
```

I'd say it's now harder to read. The more to the right my code starts to gravitate, the more I feel sorry for who needs to maintain it.. of course, I could remove a level or two of indentation by wrapping (more) bits in methods. Then it becomes easier to read, but there's a point where black-boxing every tiny bit of logic just seems redundant...

Answer (score 1):

Much cleaner, no breaks.

```
int candidate  = 0;
int [] sums = {0,0};
int index = 1;

System.out.print("Enter a number to add to first sum: ");

while((candidate = input.nextInt()) > 0){
    sums[index] = sums[index] + candidate;
    index = (index + 1)%2;

    System.out.print("Enter a number to add to " + ((index == 0) ? "first":"second" ) + " sum: ");
    }
//We print out the totals.
System.out.printf("%1s%1d%12s%1s%1d", "First sum: ", sums[0], " ", "Second sum: ", sums[1]);
```

That isn't to say you should **always** avoid breaks, but in this case you can avoid it to make your code shorter, less redundant.

Comment: much complicated to read... Modulo, incrementation + variable assignation  in the while declaration...

Comment: I think the inline-if could be moved for clarity.  For me its clear, but I can see your point.

Comment: My exit condition is logically equivalent to the the original.  The original loop doesn't need to have sumOne > in the while condition.

Comment: sorry, I confused with another answer. I upvoted finally because good factorization but a little too complicated to read.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes avoiding break is worse than using it. I would write it like this with one less break.

```
int sumOneTotal = 0;
int sumTwoTotal = 0;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number to add to first sum: ");
    //The user enters in a value for the first sum.
    int sumOne = input.nextInt();

    if (sumOne <= 0) 
        break;

    sumOneTotal += sumOne;

    System.out.print("Enter a number to add to second sum: ");
    //The user enters in a value for the second sum.
    int sumTwo = input.nextInt();

    if (sumTwo <= 0)
        break;
    sumTwoTotal += sumTwo;
}
```

You can avoid break but this doesn't make the code clearer/simpler IMHO.

```
int sumOneTotal = 0;
int sumTwoTotal = 0;
boolean okay = true;
do {
    System.out.print("Enter a number to add to first sum: ");
    //The user enters in a value for the first sum.
    int sumOne = input.nextInt();

    if (sumOne <= 0) {
        okay = false;
    } else {
        sumOneTotal += sumOne;

        System.out.print("Enter a number to add to second sum: ");
        //The user enters in a value for the second sum.
        int sumTwo = input.nextInt();

        if (sumTwo <= 0) {
            okay = false;
        } else {
            sumTwoTotal += sumTwo;
        }
} while (okay);
```

The same advice applies to using labels. Avoid them where possible unless avoiding them means doing something worse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't necissarially agree that it is always bad practice to use a `break` inside an `if`. However, that is more a matter of opinion than anything, and is not really on topic here. I will answer the part of your question that is on topic, namely: how can I fix my code to not use `break` inside an `if`.

The code below will continue to loop, asking a user for input, until they input a valid number. This avoids your original problem and has the added benefit of allowing the user a chance to enter a new number if they make a mistake, instead of exiting the loop and making them start over.

```
int sumOne = 1;
int sumTwo = 1;
int sumOneTotal = 0;
int sumTwoTotal = 0;
while(sumOne > 0 || sumTwo > 0){
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a number to add to first sum: ");
        //The user enters in a value for the first sum.
        sumOne = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter a number to add to second sum: ");
        //The user enters in a value for the second sum.
        sumTwo = input.nextInt();
    }while(sumTwo <= 0 || sumOne <= 0);

    sumOneTotal = sumOneTotal + sumOne;
    sumTwoTotal = sumTwoTotal + sumTwo;
}
//We print out the total of sumOneTotal and sumTwoTotal.
System.out.printf("%1s%1d%12s%1s%1d", "First sum: ", sumOneTotal, " ", "Second sum: ", sumTwoTotal);
```

Comment: That would solve it! However I am supposed to make the code alternate input. So it would ask for sum one, then sum two, then some one. She is very picky as to how we write this program.

Comment: @DylanKelemen no problem! see my edit. it will now loop until both numbers are valid inputs, before adding them to the total. if either is invalid, it will prompt for both numbers again, in order, as your teacher wants. please remember to upvote and accept if it is helpful =]

Answer (score 0):

```
    while (sumOne > 0 && sumTwo > 0) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number to add to first sum: ");
        sumOne = input.nextInt();
        if (sumOne > 0) {
            sumOneTotal = sumOneTotal + sumOne;
            System.out.print("Enter a number to add to second sum: ");
            sumTwo = input.nextInt();
            if (sumTwo > 0)
                sumTwoTotal = sumTwoTotal + sumTwo;
        }
    }
```

but i agree with others - there is no any sense to avoid "break"